# Formulas on the plot under each other

Tags: r

I have a curve:

```
fun <- function(x) 1/x
curve(fun)
```

I want to plot multiple formulas under each other (line breaks maybe?) without calculating Y coordinates like this:

```
text(expression(lambda[n]==2), x= 0.2, y = 80)
text(expression(gamma[n]==2), x= 0.2, y = 75)
```

[image]